# C# equivalent of powershell get-childitem -recurse while omitting certain folders

Tags: c#, powershell

I have a powershell script that I currently use when I am searching for files. I am trying to port it to c# but cannot seem to get an equivalent working.

The Powershell script is:

```
    $drives= gwmi Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DriveType=3 or DriveType=4"|select Name|foreach-object {$_.Name + "\"}


 $files=@(

  "*.txt","*.docx","*.doc"
       )



    foreach ($drive in $drives){




    $filenames = Get-ChildItem $drive -Recurse -include $files -erroraction silentlycontinue | Where {($_.FullName -notlike *Windows*) -and ($_.FullName -notlike "*Microsoft*") -and ($_.FullName -notlike "*Temp*") -and ($_.FullName -notlike "*Google*") -and ($_.FullName -notlike "*Mozilla*") -and ($_.FullName -notlike "*Recycle*") -and ($_.FullName -notlike "*tmp*")} |where-object{!($_.PSIsContainter)} | % {$_.FullName}
```

I have this c# code to search through directories but I am not sure how to omit directories and cannot find nay examples online

```
     var extensions = new List<string> { ".txt", ".doc" };
     string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(sDir, "*.*",    SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                .Where(f => extensions.IndexOf(Path.GetExtension(f)) >= 0).ToArray();
```

Thanks

Comment: it's good that Timothy Stepanski, provided you an answer, but...but...but, this SO Q&A is about helping folks with PowerShell code issues, PowerShell code that does not work.  However, your post/use case is not about non-working PowerShell code. It's I don't want to use PowerShell code in my C# app, but I want my C# app to do something which PowerShell does. So, color me confused. Why not just call the PowerShell cmdlet / code from your C# app? No raw C# porting/conversion needed. Just curious.

Comment: I think it would be harder to convert the powershell response back to c# for the rest of the script. Damned if I do and damned if I don't

Comment: ***;-}***  ---- We've all been there my friend. Life is all about challenges, discovery, creativity, for solutions; physical, mental, and emotional. ***;-}***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var extensions = new HashSet<string> { @".txt", @".doc" };
var excludedFilePatterns = new HashSet<string> { @"Microsoft", @"Temp" }; // etc, etc

var files = Directory
     .GetFiles(sDir, @"*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
     .Where(file => extensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(file)))
     .Where(file =>
     {
         var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);

         return excludedFilePatterns
             .All(excludedFilePattern =>
                 !fileName.Contains(excludedFilePattern, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
     })
     .ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks Timothy. The code looks great but when adding it to my VS project, I get the error:

Comment: Error CS0103 The name 'sDir' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Also I noticed you changed string[] files to var files. May I ask why this is and will it affect if I need to put the results into string input = files;

Comment: sDir was a variable you had declared outside the scope of the code snippet you provided, I merely carried it forward presuming it was your start point. As for the var usage, take a look at this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/var).

Comment: Ah yes, my mistake. Thanks for your help Timothy, much appreciated :)